# How to correctly make a Post request in Spring-MVC?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc

I have a view of a page with user orders, a controller, a model and a class for accessing the database using the DAO concept. However, when I try to "add an order" my `PostMapping` request is not processed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

**orders.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My Orders</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div th:include="frags/headerUser"></div>

    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h2>User Orders</h2>
    
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="order : ${ordersList}">
                <td th:text="${order.date}"></td>
                <td th:text="${order.status}"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addOrderModal">
            Add new order
        </button>

        <div class="modal" id="addOrderModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">New order</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form th:action="@{/addOrder}" method="post">
                            <!-- My form -->
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**order.java**

```
//imports
public class Order {
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private String status;
    
    //get- and set- funcs

}
```

**jdbcOrderDAO.java**

```
//imports
@Repository
public class JdbcOrderDAO implements OrderDAO {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcOrderDAO(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void addOrder(Order order) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO indent (indent_date, indent_status) VALUES (?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, order.getDate(), order.getStatus());
    }
    //...
}
```

**controllerUser.java**

```
//imports
@Controller
public class ControllerUser {
    private final JdbcOrderDAO oDAO;

    public ControllerUser(JdbcOrderDAO oDAO) {
        this.oDAO = oDAO;
    }

    //GetMappings
    
    @PostMapping("/addOrder")
    public String addOrder(@RequestParam("orderDate") Date orderDate,
                           @RequestParam("orderStatus") String orderStatus) {

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setDate(orderDate);
        order.setStatus(orderStatus);
        oDAO.addOrder(order);
        
        return "user/orders";
    }
}
```

**databaseConfig.java**

```
//imports
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String databaseUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String databasePassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(databaseUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the 'DAO concept' you can try creating a JPA entity and repository.

Using Spring Data JPA you can create an Order class and annotate it accordingly:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    private Date orderDate;
    private String orderStatus;
    /* Constructors, getters, and setters */
}
```

Then in your html form tag, you reference your entity with **th:object**, and each field with **th:field**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addOrder}" th:object="${order}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{orderStatus}"> 
    <!-- other fields -->
</form>
```

That way each field is set automatically. So in your controller you just have to pass it to the corresponding method.

```
@PostMapping("/addOrder")
public String addOrder(Order order) {
    orderRepository.save(order);
    return "user/orders";
}
```

In this case, I'm assuming you create a repository using **JpaRepository**. You can try that also instead of the way you are doing it right now. JPA automatically creates basic CRUD operations for you.

You just have to create an interface that extends JpaRepository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{}
```

And in order to call it from your Controller you just @Autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;
```

Comment: This is a learning project where I want to try out the DAO concept. Maybe you can tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: I think it has to do with the mapping of the fields from the html to the controller.

In your orders.html you are not specifying any entity or fields; but in your controller you are expecting 2 fields (orderDate and orderStatus).

In the example I showed you I specify the entity and fields with th:object and th:field, respectively and then I used them in the controller with the Order object.